# Another issue with specialised pure virtual template function (undefined reference)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

As a beginner, I have some problem regarding templates, inheritance and pure virtual functions.

Consider the following, where Probability is an abstract template instantiated as RationalProbability.

Probability.h:

```
template <class T>
class Probability
{
public:
    T value;
    //Operator overloading for + 
    virtual Probability<T>* operator+(const Probability<T>& p);
    T getValue() const { return value; }

protected:
    Probability(T val) {
        value = val;
    }
    ~Probability() {};
};
```

Probability.cpp : empty

RationalProbability.h:

```
#include "Probability.h"

class RationalProbability: public Probability<float>
{
    public:
        RationalProbability(float prob);
        virtual ~RationalProbability();
        RationalProbability* operator+(const RationalProbability& p);
};
```

RationalProbability.cpp:

```
#include "RationalProbability.h"

RationalProbability::RationalProbability(float prob): Probability(prob) {}

RationalProbability::~RationalProbability()
{
}

RationalProbability* RationalProbability::operator+(const   RationalProbability& p) {
    RationalProbability* rp = new RationalProbability(p.getValue() + this->value);
    return rp;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:undefined reference to
  Probability<float>::operator+(Probability<float> const&)
```

It is true that there is no function with that exact signature, but RationalProbability implements the template exactly with

```
RationalProbability: public Probability<float>
```

Comment: You didn't specify a pure virtual function, hence an implementation is expected.

Comment: And an `operator+()` returning a pointer to a dynamically allocated object .... blech!!!   This is not Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a base class to have an *abstract* function (a virtual function you don't implement) you should say so:

```
virtual Probability<T>* operator+(const Probability<T>& p) = 0;
```

The `= 0` is what tells the compiler that the member function is an abstract method that must be overridden by sub-classes.

If you don't have that, there *must* be a definition (implementation) of all virtual functions.

---

If you look closer at the error message it says that it's `Probability<float>::operator+` that is missing, not `RationalProbability::operator+`.

I also suggest you [read and check some canonical operator implementations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations), especially [for the binary arithmetic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators), because you should not return a pointer from the `operator+` function. It should return an object *by value*. Otherwise, how would something like `a + b + c` work if suddenly the result of one addition was a pointer?